# how to get system time format in c#,not system time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get the system **time format**. If the time in system is in **dd/mm/yy** format,then I need to create a message box to change the time format to **mm/dd/yy**..

Thanks in advance

Comment: visit here[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx]

Comment: Just for clarification: you have a DateTime object you want to display, and you want it displayed as MM/dd/yyyy regardless of what the system format is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For date

```
string dateFormate = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

For time

```
string timeFormate = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
```

Comment: It will return formats for current thread. They almost always match the one set in system settings, but that's not necessary true in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System.Globalization;

...
...
...

var systemDateFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;

var timePattern = systemDateFormat.FullDateTimePattern;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect the format of date and time set for current instance you can use following method.

```
using System.Globalization;
```

.

```
var systemFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;

var CurrentSystemDateTimePatttern= systemFormat.FullDateTimePattern;
```

But if you are looking for you own custom format regardless of system format you can use following method...

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") // Where MM is Month, dd is day and yyyy is Year in 4 Digit.
```